# Jest mock values returned by function

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs

I have a logger file as below which implements logging functionality. **uuidLogger.js**

```
const winston = require('winston'),
    CustomTransport = require('./customTransport');

function getLogger(route) {
    return winston.createLogger({
        defaultMeta: { route },
        transports: [new CustomTransport()]
    });
}
module.exports = getLogger;
```

It is imported by a function like this and used for logging **testfn.js**

```
const uuidLogger = require('./uuidLogger')('test-fn');

function testMock() {
    uuidLogger.info('Hey I am just logging');
}

module.exports = { testMock };
```

I am trying to mock uuidlogger in **testfn.js** so that I can track various methods called on uuidLogger object. I tried below approach.

```
import { testMock } from './testfn';
import getLogger from './uuidLogger';
const logger = getLogger('testfn');

jest.mock('./uuidLogger', () =>
    jest.fn(() => ({
        info: jest.fn(() => console.log('Mocked function actually called'))
    }))
);
it('verify that info method was called on returned object', () => {
    testMock('abx');
    expect(logger.info).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

It was able to mock the method called however **mock information is not getting reflected in logger.info object.**

I also tried below approach

```
import { testMock } from './testfn';
import getLogger from './uuidLogger';
jest.mock('./uuidLogger', () =>
    jest.fn(() => ({ info: jest.fn(() => console.log('Top level fn')) }))
);
const logger = {
    error: jest.fn(),
    info: jest.fn(() => {
        console.log('Overwritten fn');
    })
};

getLogger.mockReturnValue(logger);

it('shud return Winston instance', () => {
    testMock('abx');
    expect(logger.info).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Any help on how to get it will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the assertion is not done on proper variable.

Need to assert on `getLogger`

Your first approach of writing test case is proper.

Add assertion something like this:

```js
 expect(getLogger.mock.results[0].value.info).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```